# Example of custom Corda SQL statement

Tags: corda

Can anyone point me to some example code of how to obtain a JDBC connection inside a Corda flow, and execute some arbitrary SQL? I want to execute some SQL like this, and the VaultCustomQueryCriteria class won't be able to generate this (as far as I know):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(NULLIF(OBJ, '12345')), COUNT(*)
FROM SUBS
WHERE SBJ = '_abc' AND PRED = 'LEI'
```

Thanks

James

Answer (score 2):

I think you should start watching and following some of the tutorials, in your case I wuold recommend the [vault queries corda tutorial](https://docs.corda.net/api-vault-query.html) and the [persistence API corda tutorial](https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html)

Answer (score 1):

James, please take a look at `CustomVaultQuery` (and associated `CustomVaultQueryTest`) under docs\source\example-code